# Python / Tweepy - ImportError:No module named 'tweepy.auth in virtual environment (python 3)

Tags: python, ubuntu, tweepy

I am trying to create a twitter bot using tweepy and uploading it in a virtual environment where it can run 24/7.

Unfortunately I get stuck on the basics.

First I could not import tweepy for python 3 (I believe my virtual environment ran python 2.7 for some reason) and I had to git clone it (`git clone git://github.com/joshthecoder/tweepy.git`) and of course install python3 again.

Even after doing so  I keep getting 
**ImportError: No module named 'tweepy.auth'**

This is the code I run. Any suggestions?

```
import tweepy
from tweepy.auth import OAuthHandler


auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key,consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token,access_token_secret)
auth.secure = True
api = tweepy.API(auth)
```

My virtual environment is a server in digital ocean running on ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
import tweepy
from tweepy import auth.OAuthHandler
```

Usually it's something like that when I have that issue.

**EDIT**

I'm not sure you actually need the second import line. This is from the Tweepy docs

```
import tweepy

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

public_tweets = api.home_timeline()
for tweet in public_tweets:
    print tweet.text
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for the answer, unfortunately it does not work.

'    from tweepy import auth.OAuthHandler'
                           ^
'SyntaxError: invalid syntax'

Comment: from tweepy import auth.OAuthHandler' 

^ 

'SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Wait why do you need the second line anyway? Later on you have tweepy.OAuthHandler?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to helo, unfortunately I get this:

`Traceback (most recent call last):`
`File "tweepy-run.py", line 29, in <module>`
`auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key,consumer_secret)`
`AttributeError: module 'tweepy' has no attribute 'OAuthHandler'`

Comment: Does changing the 3rd line of your code to tweepy.auth.OAuthHandler work? Because if not, then you won't be able to import it like that anyway. You may need to try updating or reinstalling tweepy if it keeps up.

Comment: Unfortunately no, I get this message
AttributeError: module 'tweepy' has no attribute 'auth'

I think I may have not installed tweepy correctly in my virtual environment. Would you have some suggestion on installing tweepy in a way other than pip install tweepy which installs it in the python2.7 version and not the third.

Comment: When I want to make sure I use the right pip, I navigate to the directory where it sits and run it from there. pip3 may also work, depending on your setup.